# Como lista um grupo de coordenadas(latitude, longitude) em um tabela SQL Oracle 11g em um raio

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Estou precisando listar um grupo de coordenadas em raio de 500m.

Tenho uma tabela de nome `TB_COORDENADAS`, com as colunas `LATITUDE` e `LONGITUDE`.

Desejo apontar uma coordenada (lat, lng) e listar todas as coordenadas na tabela que estejam em um raio de 500m.

Qual seria a melhor solução para meu problema?

Já encontrei soluções que funcionariam no MySQL, mas no Oracle 11g não rodam.  Preciso que o resultado seja uma lista de latitude e longitude e não a distância entre um ponto e outro.